# Where is all the clipboard data stored in Windows?

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is the data I copy to clipboard stored temporarily (maybe in the RAM) or is a permanent log of all the clipboard data stored in the hard drive?

If its stored anywhere, how can we clear it (by shredding). I checked [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard), but couldn't understand anything.

I'm asking because I frequently copy passwords and other sensitive data to the clipboard and don't want to be insecure.

**Note**: I use Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article written for Windows 8 / 8.1

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/how-to-clear-the-clipboard/024f716b-c1c8-4c1d-853b-fa2a40b67c8c

> A clipboard is nothing but a buffer that stores data that we copy and
> paste. We never wonder that when we copy a text and paste it as many
> times as we want, where is the text saved for us? Yes it is the
> clipboard where the text is temporarily saved. And a clipboard manager
> enhances these functions of copy, cut, and paste. Anyways, we can also
> experiment with this buffer named clipboard. If you repeatedly copy
> and paste large files or image files, pasting may take time and
> deliver low performance. So it’s sometimes necessary to clear up the
> clipboard to clear memory.
>
> Step1: How to clear the clipboard in Windows 8.
>
> 1. Press Windows Key + R to open Run window.
> 2. Type cmd /c “echo off | clip” andpress Enter.
>
> You can also create a shortcut with location as the command cmd /c
> “echo off | clip”. Whenever you want to clear clipboard, double click
> on it.
>
> 1. Right Click in an empty space on the desktop and Go to New and click on Shortcut.
> 2. Now Create Shortcut window opens. Now type the following text cmd /c “echo off | clip”. Click Next.
> 3. Name the shortcut as Clear Clipboard. Click Finish.

Answer (score -1):

It's held in memory, the best way to clear it is by using the history

Press : Windows + v

that'll being the clipboard history, from there you can remove specific items or clear all using the ... button on the top right.

Comment: dont see anything by pressing Win+V, ( I use Windows 8.1)

Comment: Ah yes, the clipboard history is a windows 10 feature.